# FIREFOX fade in/out div background image not working

Tags: css, image, firefox, background, fadein

I have a div with a slideshow background image. It works perfectly on Safari and Android mobile, but doesn't work fully on Firefox : The fade in effect doesn't appear.

```css
@keyframes fadeBG {
  25% {
    background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1110x220/?beach");
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1110x220/?castle");
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1110x220/?lake");
  }
}
/* NOTE: images of different aspect ratios will stretch and move */

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1110x220/weekly');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fadeBG 16s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.15, 1) infinite;
  box-shadow: 0 -100vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron my-2">
    <h1>Background Slideshow</h1>
    <p>CSS only animated slideshow</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could anybody point me to the right direction? Thx

Comment: I think there _should_ be no fade effect, according to the specification. The animation _type_ of `background-image` is _discrete_, and that means no interpolation of the value whatsoever, but that it will just switch from one to the other. If other browsers are doing something _extra_, instead of strictly following the specification - that's not Firefox' fault.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thank you very much for your messages, since my post à started from 0 and made it another way :)